# WordPress custom CSS file overrided by internal CSS

Tags: css

I have started to convert my static page to WordPress theme. While I am doing this I have a place where the position of the background image of a section has to be set with values like `background-position:0 80%;`.

When I add the CSS to my custom CSS file which is main.css I found out there an internal CSS which is overriding my CSS like `background-postion:center !important`.

Then I changed my CSS to `background-position:0 80%; !important`

But it still doesn't work and I found out my CSS file is included before the internal CSS in the head ( **by view page source code**).

Now what I want to know is how can I change the order or how can I import my custom CSS (**main.css**) file after the internal CSS code?

Comment: First of all you should fix the main theme. There is no logical reason to use !important in a theme, if it is built all by the theme creator itself. Maybe try using a theme by someone who actually understands his/her job ;)

Comment: WordPress themes use the style.css file so make sure your declaration is at the bottom of that first of all, and also that you're editing a child of a theme, not the theme itself (unless this theme is custom that you built yourself, of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it should be: `background-position:0 80% !important;`
You said this style is applied to sections. How?
If you just add another selector, like instead using:

```
article{
background-position:0 80% !important;
}
```

use:

```
body article{
background-position:0 80% !important;
}
```

it may just work without any hacks.

Comment: I already tried it. But it's adding some internal css and overriding my custom css file. Actually what I want to know is how can I add my custom css file after the internal css styles.I tried the priority things too.It didn't work

Comment: It is only overriding it because it has a more specific selector. If your css were to have a more specific selector (meaning more things in the selector than the internal file, like: `html body div#main .main-container article`), then it would override the internal css no matter where it is on the page.
You could also register a css file with just the fix for the article, not enqueue it, and then enqueue it just before the `wp_footer();`, then it would load that file in the footer.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much for your time and information

Answer (score 0):

Style blocks that aren't from the stylesheet stink. I truly despise it when theme developers put them in their theme. The only thing worse is inline styles (ie ). Those are virtually impossible to overcome.

In your case, there's a couple of hack-tastic way to overcome this hacky issue.

In your child theme's functions.php file, you can use the following (Admittedly hacky) solution:

// We're adding a HIGH priority of 9999 which should cause this to be output AFTER the theme's bad styles.

```
add_action('wp_head', 'fix_bad_theme_styles', 9999);

function fix_bad_theme_styles() { ?>
    <style type="text/css" data-type="vc_custom-css">
            #site-header:not(.shrink) .site-title { padding: 1px 0 !important; }
    </style>
<?php }
```

If that doesn't work, an even hackier way would be to put the style in the footer. It'll work, but it's not best-practice (as if any of this solution is!):

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'fix_bad_theme_styles');
```

Comment: Is this the only way that I overcome this issue. Is it impossible to add my custom css file after the css styles which are written by the WordPress it self?